# Sum of Products of Z scores - why does this =( n-1) in a straight line

Tags: correlation

As above, why does the sum of the product of the Z scores always equal n - 1 in a perfectly correlated scenario ??

Comment: Is this a question from a course or textbook? If so, please add the `[self-study]`
tag & read its [wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Answer (score 1):

Because this reads something like a homework question (and I could be wrong), I will start by only providing a hint:

There is a concise relationship between the product of the $z$-scores for two variables (say $x$ and $y$) and the correlation between the two variables, $r_{xy}$.  (For this exploration, lets assume we are working with samples and not populations.)

I hope this starts you on a fruitful path.  Again, happy to comment further as need be.